# The size of checkpoint gets larger and larger without using state in tumblingProcessingTimeWindows

Tags: apache-flink, checkpoint, pyflink

You can see that the size of checkpoint gets larger and larger, and never reduces.

[image: checkpoints graph]

In web UI, you can see that it is caused by TumblingProcessingTimeWindows, and I found that the size of checkpoint is nearly equal to the Bytes Received of TumblingProcessingTimeWindows. the job runs OK, and the logic of the process runs successfully.
[image]

However, in my apply function, I do not use state to save anything, so it is impossible to be caused by the content of state.

```
ret_stream = (log_stream
              .map(MyMapFunction())
              .filter(lambda x: self.get_key(x) is not None)
              .key_by(self.get_key, key_type=Types.STRING())
              .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
              .apply(MyWindowFunction()))

class MyWindowFunction(WindowFunction[tuple, tuple, str, TimeWindow]:
    def apply(self, key: KEY, window: W, inputs: Iterable[IN]) -> Iterable[OUT]:
        logger.info({
            "key": key,
            "data": [data for _, _, data in inputs]
        })
        return []
```

Another performance is that TaskManager Threads keeps growing.
[image: TM threads]

I do not understand why the checkpoint keeps growing. I set nowatermark and checkpoint interval is 1min.

Comment: Are you using the embedded RocksDB state backend?

Comment: i use HashMapStateBackend

Answer (score 0):

Windows do keep state. In particular, the events assigned to each window are kept in a list until the window is triggered, and these lists are checkpointed. Most sources and sinks also keep some state.

The amount of state kept by the windows is going to depend on the total throughput, which seems to be what you have observed.

If it's possible to rewrite your window function to do its work incrementally via `reduce` or `aggregate` (e.g., if you are computing a simple aggregation such as a count, sum, min, max, or average), then the size of the state and checkpoints could shrink dramatically.

Comment: Thank for your answer,  i sure that the window is triggered, because logger log successfully in apply function. The events list will be cleaned  until the window is triggered, as your said. so the size of checkpoint will reduce. On the other hand, my source is kafka, and it's throughput is dynamically, not always rising. In my opinion, the checkpoint will up and down.but the checkpoint is always rising. it is very strange.
I will try to solve this problem by rewriting my window function via reduce.

Comment: I agree that there is something of a mystery here. With RocksDB this wouldn't be surprising, since the checkpoints will contain tombstones until compaction occurs, but with the heap-based state backend this is unexpected -- unless the traffic being processed is also growing linearly.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem by setting trigger function that i rewrite.

```
class MyProcessingTimeTrigger(ProcessingTimeTrigger):
    def on_processing_time(self,
                           time: int,
                           window: TimeWindow,
                           ctx: 'Trigger.TriggerContext') -> TriggerResult:
        return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE

ret_stream = (log_stream
                      .map(MyMapFunction())
                      .filter(lambda x: self.get_key(x) is not None)
                      .key_by(self.get_key, key_type=Types.STRING())
                      .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                      .trigger(MyProcessingTimeTrigger())
                      .apply(MyWindowFunction()))
```

but i still not understand why input data not clean after window function close

Comment: That's weird. What version of Flink is this? What are the source and sink? Anything else I might need if I want to try to reproduce this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).